# How to show Partial Views slowly, without display:none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I'm working on app for creating CV in asp.net mvc. User can add dynamically new Skill, Education etc, and it is shown by Partial View.

**Main View**

```
    <div id="divSkill" class="form-group">
        @foreach (var s in Model.Skills)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_Skill", s);
        }
    </div>
        <input class ="add" type="button" data-field="#divSkill" data-url="/People/_Skill/" value="Add skill" />
```

**Ajax**

```
    $('.add').click(function () {
        var u = $(this).attr('data-url');
        var d = $(this).attr('data-field');
        $.ajax({
            url: u,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/html',
            success: function (content) {
                $(content).appendTo(d).show('slow');
            }
        });
    });
```

I wanted Partails to show slowly, so i added `$(content).appendTo(d).show('slow');` and in css class for Partial View `display: none;`. 
It works great with new Partials, but when I refresh site then all Partials in foreach are invisible because of `display: none;`.

Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: In the success callback, you could append a hidden element, append the partial to it, and the show the hidden element using `.show('slow')`

Comment: It works. Thanks!